# DataTables currency sorting

Tags: jquery, regex, sorting, datatables

My question is about the sorting of my specific type of currency
I have the following type of currency:

[image]

It is the 5th row in my entire database table, as such

[image]

I need to be able to sort the prices for the datatables, i was told that this would work:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "currency-pre": function (a) {
        a = (a === "-") ? 0 : a.replace(/[^\d\-]/g, "");
        return parseFloat(a);
    },
    "currency-asc": function (a, b) {
        return a - b;
    },
    "currency-desc": function (a, b) {
        return b - a;
    }
});
```

However, this does not work in my case.

I have 2 possible outcomes for the datatable initialisation:

```
$('table').dataTable( {
        "aoColumns": [{"sType": "currency"}],
        "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
        "columnDefs": [
            { "type": "de_datetime", targets: 0 },
            { "orderable": false, "targets": 2 },
            { "type": "currency", targets: 5 }
        ],
        stateSave: true
    } );
```

and also

```
 $('table').DataTable( {
    "ajax": "<?php echo SCRIPT_URL; ?>api/admin_overview_quotations_json.php",
    "columns": [
        { "data": "post_time" },
        { "data": "number" },
        { "data": "company" },
        { "data": "reference" },
        { "data": "total_price" },
        { "data": "status" },
        { "data": "sales_call_date" },
        { "data": "quotation_id" }
    ],
    "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
        "columnDefs": [
            { "type": "de_datetime", targets: 0 },
            { "type": "de_datetime", targets: 6 },
            { "orderable": false, "targets": 1 },
            { "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                return '<a type="button" class="btn btn-primary view_by_id hidden-xs hidden-md" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view" data-url=<?php echo SCRIPT_URL; ?>api/admin_download_quotation.php?quotation_id=' + data + '&action=view" data-tooltip="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="<?php echo ASLang::get('View offer'); ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" aria-hidden="true"></span></a> <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary" href="<?php echo SCRIPT_URL; ?>admin/new-project.php?type=offer&id=' + data + '&action=manage" data-tooltip="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="<?php echo ASLang::get('Edit offer'); ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></a> <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary" href="<?php echo SCRIPT_URL; ?>admin/new-project.php?type=offer&id=' + data + '&action=order" data-tooltip="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="<?php echo ASLang::get('Make order from offer'); ?>"><i class="icon-basket"></i></a> <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary hidden-xs hidden-md" href="<?php echo SCRIPT_URL; ?>api/admin_download_quotation.php?quotation_id=' + data + '&action=download" data-tooltip="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="<?php echo ASLang::get('Download quotation'); ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span></a> <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary visible-xs visible-md" href="<?php echo SCRIPT_URL; ?>api/admin_download_quotation.php?quotation_id=' + data + '&action=view" target="_blank" data-tooltip="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="<?php echo ASLang::get('View offer'); ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>';
                },
                "targets": 7
            }
        ],
        stateSave: true,
    "language": {
        "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Dutch.json"
    }
} );
```

depending on a specific constant, but the fact remains that the price needs to be sorted.

This of course, is my question. Why does the sorting not work? I've tried logging in the extension for oSort, but this also does not log when clicking.

I have tried the following regexes too:

```
(/[^\d\-]/g
[^\d\-]
```

but this, also, was to no avail.

Comment: What do you mean it don't work? It dosen't sort? It sort alphabetically? It display an error message?

Comment: m.nachury sorry for not making it clear enough, it does not sort the currency correctly in any way.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am currently struggling with the same problem,

Comment: @Yoshi I have been unable to.